# Get Fire base real time database using where condition

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to fetch data from Firebase Real-time database using `where` condition.
I want to get all data based on a specific keyword. please my JSON data below.

[image]

I want to fetch data where a company is equal to Balaji Seeds. And I want to print proname,proid.

I tried below code.

```
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference = database.getReference();
    Query query = mDatabaseReference.child("Products").orderByChild("company").equalTo("Balaji Seeds");


        query.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildKey) {
                Map<String, Object> newPost = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();

                Toast.makeText(CompanyCategoryList.this, "ProName: "+newPost.get("proname"),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }


        });
```

I hope you understand my concern. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Realtime Database queries operate on a list of child nodes. Your data structure is deeply nested, which makes it harder to query.

In your current data model, you can run a query on `/Products/Vegetable_Seeds/Chili` and then get the child nodes nodes under that where `company` is equal to `Balaji Seeds`. But the data model does not allow querying across all `Products` for that node.

If you want to allow this query, you'll either have to change your current model to be a flat list, or add an additional data structure where you keep the data needs for the look up of the products for a company.

Also see:

- [Firebase query if child of child contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value)
- [Firebase Query Double Nested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested)
- the video series [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s)